# How do I prevent Cygwin's XWin Server automatically starting xterm?

Tags: windows, cygwin, xterm, cygwin-x

Whenever I start Cygwin's X server using the "XWin Server" link in my Start menu, or by running `startxwin` from a Cygwin shell, I automatically get an xterm window appearing, which I neither want nor need.

How do I avoid that?

(Question inspired by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393462/cannot-launch-git-gui-using-cygwin-on-windows/9418800#comment14362287_9418800) by [Stijn Vanpoucke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387496/stijn-vanpoucke) over on Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that startxwin's behavior has changed since @me_and originally answered the question, so simply creating an empty .startxwinrc in your home directory won't work anymore.

I found an answer [here](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2014-12/msg00049.html). In essence when the last command in .startxwinrc exits, the server will exit. If you want to prevent that, you can put this as the last line in your .startxwinrc:

```
sleep inf
```

This won't start any client programs, but will also prevent .startxwinrc from exiting.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. I had to type: `exec sleep infinity` as shown here: http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-startxwinrc-exit

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE**: This answer is now out of date. For an up-to-date answer, see [user551570's answer below](https://superuser.com/a/871329/21002).

From `man startxwin`:

> If  no  specific  client  program  is  given  on  the command line, `startxwin` will look for a file in the user's home directory called `.startxwinrc` to run as a shell script to start up client programs.  If no such file exists, `startxwin` will  use  the  following  as  a default:
>
> ```
> xterm  -geometry  +1+1  -n  login  -display  :0
> ```

Thus, to avoid having any program start up when you start the X Server, you want a blank `.startxwinrc` file. Just run the following from a Cygwin prompt:

```
touch ~/.startxwinrc
```

Comment: This solution was good for a long time, but now with the last update it is not. Using an empty `.startxwinrc` results in the immediate disappearance of the X server. :-(

Comment: @Notinlist So it does. That's a bit sad. I'll try and investigate and find a new solution; it appears the system is somewhat more complicated now, and I can't trivially work out how it's supposed to work…

Answer (score 3):

As of [November 2014](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2014-11/msg00029.html), the latest versions of `startxwin` use `xinit` to start the Cygwin/X server, which is actually called `XWin.exe`. The process goes something like this:

1. You call `startxwin`
2. `startxwin` creates a new `.Xauthority` file and one called `.serverauth.1234` (where `1234` changes each time you start X)
3. `startxwin` sets up some client and server parameters
4. `startxwin` calls `xinit` with the client and server parameters, including some optional shell scripts and a reference to the auth file.
5. `xinit` starts the X server, running some of the rc scripts
6. `xinit` starts the client (usually `xterm`) or client rc script. **We want to avoid this**
7. When you close the client or the client rc script finishes, `xinit` shuts down the X server. **If we avoid step 6, we also need to avoid this**

It is possible to run `XWin.exe` directly from within a Bash login shell, without the surrounding tasks that `startxwin` and `xinit` perform. The main advantage of this is that it behaves like we want: the X server starts and remains running. Unfortunately, since there is no `.Xauthority` file passed during startup, your X server would permit any local process to connect to it, which is insecure.

Fortunately it's `xinit` that does most of the stuff we don't want. There's a quick hack that bypasses `xinit` but keeps the remaining elements of `startxwin` that are related to the server itself.

**TL;DR:** In `startxwin`, there's a line near the bottom that reads:

```
eval xinit \"$client\" $clientargs -- \"$server\" $display $serverargs
```

Change that line to:

```
eval \"$server\" $display $serverargs
```

From now on, the `startxwin` script will call `XWin.exe` directly, rather than calling `xinit`. Obviously this will disable any client rc scripts, but we didn't want those in the first place. It also means that X will continue running without needing a client process to keep it alive (i.e. keep `xinit` from killing it).

Answer (score 0):

I've made it a habit to start Cygwin X with startxwin(.exe).
My .startxwinrc file reads as follows:

```
X :0 -rootless mrxvt  -geometry  +1+1  -n  login  -display  :0 -tt ImTabbed
```

So far, it's worked. The only error I get concerns the display still being "open" by another X process. This error specifies a certain file the X server generates by default for every session. The Cygwin folks are aware that it doesn't get deleted when the session terminates.

So I wrote an alias to "cure" that:

```
alias freex='rm /tmp/.X0-lock'
```

I put the same line -- the part in between the quotes, at any rate -- in my .bashrc and .bash_profile files in case I should forget to do it myself.

HTH.

**BZT**

Comment: This isn't really an answer to this question; with rewording it could be, but I think this would be better suited as a separate question and answer (as I did here) about handling the error you're seeing. You can then link to that question in the comments to this one.