# Create CMD/shortcut to run Cygwin X Program and hide TTY

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, batch-file, cygwin

I have successfully setup Virt-Manager on Windows and am looking to streamline the launch as its a bit cumbersum.. (So is the installation...)

Currently the only working way for me to launch Virt-Manager is to login the terminal and then type the following:

```
startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1 &
virt-manager
```

I noticed there is a GUI executable in the cygwin folder called XWin.exe, perhaps I can set that to autolaunch Virt-Manager? At this time it is my only use for Cygwin and if I find another use for Cygwin I see me having a separate folder for each purpose.

Note: I tried creating the file `.startxwinrc` with `virt-manager` inside, but then when i run `startxwin` it just fails completely to load virt-manager :(

I created a script with the above code and it works by just logging in and executing `./virtmgr.sh`, but the TTY stays open in the background.

I also haven't figured out how to launch that script via CMD/Bat file.

Any Advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Script :

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /home/Admin/virtmgr.sh
```

To use .startxwinrc:

End file with `sleep inf`

[How do I prevent Cygwin's XWin Server automatically starting xterm?](https://superuser.com/questions/435768/how-do-i-prevent-cygwins-xwin-server-automatically-starting-xterm)

My issue with .startxwinrc was the above post, it exits unless you add sleep inf to the autostart file. I was able to get my script to run as well via the above code snippet, and the tty exited after the script.

I did REMOVE the shebang from the script and added entire `/full/path/to/binary`, but I didn't test if it's needed as I chose to perfect using `.startxwinrc`. My though was that I called `bash` via the CLI options so it didn't need the shebang, and I just used full paths in case that was the problem.